# How do i place a water mark image on image that i just took a picture of it in Android?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, watermark

How do I place a water mark (company logo, image) on an picture I've just taken?

I need to do it on Android.

Can you please help?

Comment: Is it about just showing a picture with a watermark on it, or saving the picture with a watermark?

Comment: it's placing a watermark on image and save after that showing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using any of [these jar's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459701/how-can-i-watermark-an-image-in-java) in Android.

Im4Java looks most promising.

Comment: That doesn't work, i want to use it in Android SDK, not a java application, i think it would be obvious?

Comment: Did you even try? [Here is how to add an external jar to and android application](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eY_uqi_qIz0)

Comment: I have followed after the instructions and i still not able to use the Thumbnails.of(...) i receive this error:
The type java.awt.image.BufferedImage cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: This is the error i receive:

The type java.awt.image.BufferedImage cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Answer (score 4):

You can draw the bitmap to a Canvas, and use the Canvas [drawText methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) or [drawBitmap methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) to add text or image. Ex:

```
drawingCache = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(drawingCache);
Paint paint = new Paint();

// Draw your bitmap to the canvas
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);

Paint watermarkPaint = new Paint();
watermarkPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
watermarkPaint.setAlpha(150);
watermarkPaint.setTextSize(30);
watermarkPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
watermarkPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

canvas.drawText("Watermark", 100, 100, watermarkPaint);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  public static Bitmap mark(Bitmap src) {
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();
    int pw=w-170;
    int ph=h-170;
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, 150, 150, true);

    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    paint.setAlpha(50);
    paint.setTextSize(20);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setUnderlineText(false);
    canvas.drawBitmap(resized,pw,ph,paint);
    return result;
    }
```