# How can I overlay / insert custom text into javax.print documents (pdf, doc, docx...)?

Tags: java, printing, watermark

I print documents (pdf, doc, docx...) via `javax.print` and it works fine, but I need to add a custom overlay text on any place at document; the text is necessary to insert a printed reference from my code to the document.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe adding text (watermarking) is an aspect of `javax.print`.

You can pre-process each page of each document via `Graphics2d` and add in the text/graphic individually based on that document's type, then send that document to the printer.

There are several threads here and elsewhere on "watermarking", which is essentially what you're looking to do.  The process is different based on the type of document you're working with.  Single-page images, multi-page images, PDFs, DOCs, and DOCXs all require different ways to be processed.

Here are some threads to get you started:

- **GIF/JPEG/TIFF:** [How can I watermark an image in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459701/how-can-i-watermark-an-image-in-java)
- **GIF/JPEG/TIFF:** [Adding a watermark over an image programmatically using Java](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/graphics/adding-a-watermark-over-an-image-programmatically-using-java)
- **DOCX:** [Creating watermark programmatically](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/creating-watermark-programatically-t1840.html)
- **PDF:** [Watermarking PDFs via iText](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/events/Watermarking)