# How to watermark images uploaded into S3

Tags: amazon-s3, watermark

We would like to watermark images automatically, after its uploaded to S3. How do we achieve this using a java based library?

Answer (score 0):

The flow should be as follows to watermark images whenever it is uploaded:

1. Raw image (without watermark) is uploaded to S3 bucket
2. Use S3 events (such as [s3:ObjectCreated:*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations) based on your need) to trigger Lambda. Hence, you need to configure [S3 event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html) destination as Lambda.
3. Lambda shall apply watermark and upload watermarked image

NOTE: If you don't use Lambda, other way is via SQS/SNS as event destination, and your worker shall take request from it and apply watermarking.

Comment: What library should be used for watermarking the image, when the lambda is triggered.

Comment: Pls refer https://www.codejava.net/java-se/graphics/adding-a-watermark-over-an-image-programmatically-using-java OR old thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459701/how-can-i-watermark-an-image-in-java

Comment: I need watermark library without awt(java.awt.*)